# Python interpreter Crash while using C extension for python

Tags: python, c, ctypes, python-c-extension

I am using ctypes module in python to write a library in C, and then access it from python. Here is my C code :

```
#import <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void convolution(int *array, int length) {
    int i;
    int p = 0;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        array[i] += 1;
     }
}
```

And here is my python code :

```
import ctypes
import numpy
import locate_file
working_directory = locate_file.locate_file()

_convolution_ = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(working_directory +'libconvolution.so')

class image_type() : 

    def from_param(self,param) : 
        typename = type(param).__name__
        if hasattr(self,'from_'+typename) : 
            return getattr(self,'from_'+typename)(param)
        else : 
            raise TypeError('type %s not supported' %typename)

    def from_list(self,param) : 
        c_array = numpy.ascontiguousarray(param,dtype=int)
        pointer = c_array.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p)

    def from_tuple(self,param) : 
        return self.from_list(param)

    def from_ndarray(self,param) : 
        return self.from_list(param)

image_type_ = image_type()

_convolution_.convolution.argtypes = [image_type_,ctypes.c_int]
_convolution_.convolution.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

def convolution(array) : 
    _convolution_.convolution(array,ctypes.c_int(len(array)))
    return None

m = [1,2,3,4,5]
convolution(m)
```

The problem is that every time I run this python code, my python crashes. I know that not initializing the argtypes and restypes of a function in ctypes can cause crashes in python, but I believe I have got it correct. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with cython, but what's the `image_type_` in `_convolution_.convolution.argtypes = [image_type_,ctypes.c_int]`?

Comment: @Mr.E it is an instance of the image_type class that I defined, which is basically a class that does the type checking and conversion of python objects to ctypes objects

Comment: I think it's cause `from_list` is not returning anything. It should return `pointer`

Comment: @Mr.E yup, i think that was it. Thanks a lot. Why don't you write an answer and I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: It's ok, I haven't done anything. Glad it worked